# Add query args if website open in mobile

Tags: functions, url-rewriting, query

how do I add a custom query in the URL if my website open in mobile?

for example, if open on desktop show: https://example.com
I want in mobile URL like https://example.com/?mode=app

I want to add "?mode=app" only if in mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery can solve this problem - can you try this.

```
jQuery(document).load(jQuery(window).bind("resize", checkPosition));
function checkPosition() {
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
        window.location.replace("https://example.com/?mode=app");
    }
}
```